# PPPD access to networks behind router

Tags: routing, openvpn, pppd

I have an OperWRT router with OPenVPN and PPPD servers configured.

Network topology is like follow:
[image: Network topology]

I have problem configuring PPPD to push routes B,C to A.
Client A, when connected to router via PPPD, has access to D, but not to B/C
On the other side machines on D network has access to B and C without any extra configuration.

Right now I add static route on client with `route add ...` command, but this is inconvienent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cause the user that created the question has admited on one of the answers that "A Client" from the question is a Windows machine. Handling routing on Windows machines on a pptp connection can be better answered at other StackExchange communities like superuser.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option that exists inside pptp(Client) is to enforce default route through ppp server:

[image: default gateway config]

And at the server there is no way to "push" routes the same way it can be done using an OpenVPN server. [Microsoft KB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958006.aspx)

Taking a look at the [How VPN Works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779919(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_vpn_how_dkma) page from Microsft it explicitly says that you will need to rely on other protocols(like RIP) to create dinamic routng environment:

> ## Dynamic Routing
>
> By implementing a dynamic routing protocol, such as RIP or Open Shortest Path First (OSPF), administrators can configure routers to exchange routing information with each other as needed.

If Linux is client, this is a solution: It is distribution dependent, but on CentOS(depending on version being used) you can create the file `/etc/ppp/ip-up.local` or `/etc/ppp/ip-up` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
/sbin/ip route add 192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
```

I'm assuming that `192.168.1.1` as the ip to traffic manually routes to those networks here. Isn't something `192.168.100.0/24`?

To auto delete those routes when disconnecting a pptp tunnel, just create a `/etc/ppp/ip-down.local` file with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/ip route del 192.168.10.0/24 
/sbin/ip route del 192.168.20.0/24
```

Comment: the clients are on windows machines. I thought about some kind of hooks, but honestly the elegant solution would be to push the networks somehow to the clients. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Well, then this question should be asked at superuser.com, cause it does not belongs to Unix... Even with a Linux/Unix server running, your problem is with the Windows client, should be better answered there...

Comment: And also, the pptp stack does not have features to push routes like OpenVPN does so, adding routes client-side is the best you can do here to create the expected solution ;) - The only thing you can force is to "make pptp the default route"... but this will make ALL traffic go through the server, and this can be an issue in some circumstances...

Comment: if pptp does not support pushing routes the this is a legitimate answer.

Comment: Let me put this on my answer then..